# What is blocking my main thread in this Discord Bot?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py, python-asyncio

## Description

First and foremost, I'm fairly new to async/await development, especially with Python. At this moment, I've been developing a Discord bot where players can execute `slots <bet>`. An embed is displayed with emojis that are edited.

[image: Slots embed]

When you first invoke the command, the embed showcases a rotating emoji gif that is then 'edited' to be the real emoji after a few seconds (to give the impression that the slots are 'spinning'):

[image]

After it's complete, the player can select the "retry" functionality to repeat the process over again. So, all in all, the flow is this:

1. Player invokes 'slot' command `slots <bet>`
2. 3 "Rotating" emojis appear and after 0.5 seconds, 1 after the other are switched to the 'static' verison
3. The player can click the "retry" button and the process repeats.

## Code

`utilities.py`

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps, partial

def sync_to_async(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def run(*args, loop=None, executor=None, **kwargs):
        if loop is None:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        pfunc = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, pfunc)

    return run
```

`slotmachine.py`

```
import asyncio
import random
from enum import Enum
from typing import Union

from discord import Color, Embed, Message, Reaction, User
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Context

from utilities import sync_to_async

import arrow

class SlotMachine:
    class Reel(Enum):
        BANANA = ""
        CHERRY = ""
        GRAPE = ""
        DOLLAR = ""
        MONEY = ""

    symbols = list(Reel)
    animated_emoji = "<a:slots:765434893781041183>"
    row_of_three_payout = {
        Reel.BANANA: 2,
        Reel.CHERRY: 4,
        Reel.GRAPE: 8,
        Reel.DOLLAR: 15,
        Reel.MONEY: 20,
    }
    row_of_two_payout = {
        Reel.BANANA: 1,
        Reel.CHERRY: 2,
        Reel.GRAPE: 4,
        Reel.DOLLAR: 0,
        Reel.MONEY: 0,
    }

    def __init__(self, ctx, bot, user, coins, bet):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.bot = bot
        self.user = user
        self.bet = bet
        self.profit = 0
        self.initial_coins = coins
        self.coins = coins
        self.message = None

    @sync_to_async
    def has_row_of_three(self, slots: list) -> bool:
        if all(i == slots[0] for i in slots):
            return SlotMachine.row_of_three_payout[slots[0]]

    @sync_to_async
    def has_row_of_two(self, slots: list) -> bool:
        if slots[0] == slots[1]:
            return True
        elif slots[1] == slots[2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    async def calculate_payout_multiplier(self, slots: list):
        has_three, has_two = await asyncio.gather(
            self.has_row_of_three(slots), self.has_row_of_two(slots)
        )
        if has_three:
            return SlotMachine.row_of_three_payout[slots[0]]
        elif has_two:
            return SlotMachine.row_of_two_payout[slots[1]]
        else:
            return 0

    @sync_to_async
    def generate_embed(self, embed_color, multiplier, slots):
        embed = Embed(title=f"Slots ", color=embed_color)
        embed.add_field(
            name="Spin",
            value=f"{' | '.join(slots)}",
            inline=False,
        )
        multiplier = f"{multiplier}x" if multiplier > 0 else "None"
        embed.add_field(name="Multiplier", value=multiplier)
        embed.add_field(name="Profit", value=self.profit)
        embed.add_field(name="Coins", value=self.coins)
        embed.add_field(name="Again?", value="React with  to play again.")
        embed.set_footer(text=self.user, icon_url=self.user.avatar_url)
        return embed

    async def play(self):
        slots = [random.choice(SlotMachine.symbols) for _ in range(3)]
        payout_multiplier = await self.calculate_payout_multiplier(slots)
        return (self.bet * payout_multiplier, payout_multiplier, slots)

    @sync_to_async
    def generate_spin_embed(self, display) -> Embed:
        embed = Embed(title=f"Slots ", color=Color.from_rgb(0, 0, 0))
        embed.add_field(
            name="Spin",
            value=" | ".join(display),
            inline=False,
        )
        embed.set_footer(text=self.user, icon_url=self.user.avatar_url)
        return embed

    async def spin_animation(self, slots) -> None:
        display = [SlotMachine.animated_emoji] * 3
        embed = await self.generate_spin_embed(display)
        await self.message.edit(embed=embed)
        for i in range(len(slots)):
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            display[i] = slots[i].value
            embed = await self.generate_spin_embed(display)
            await self.message.edit(embed=embed)

    def is_valid_reaction(self, reaction: Reaction, user: User):
        return (
            user == self.user
            and str(reaction.emoji) in ("")
            and reaction.message.id == self.message.id
        )

    async def game_loop(self):
        has_busted = False
        is_first = True
        self.message = await self.ctx.send(embed=Embed(title="⌛ Loading..."))
        try:
            while not has_busted:
                money_out, multiplier, slots = await self.play()
                self.profit = money_out - self.bet
                self.coins += self.profit
                await self.spin_animation(slots)

                if self.coins <= 0:
                    self.coins = 0
                    has_busted = True
                    await self.message.edit(
                        embed=await self.generate_embed(
                            Color.red(), multiplier, [s.value for s in slots]
                        )
                    )
                else:
                    if self.profit == 0:
                        embed_color = Color.from_rgb(0, 0, 0)
                    elif self.profit > 0:
                        embed_color = Color.green()
                    else:
                        embed_color = Color.red()

                    embed = await self.generate_embed(
                        embed_color, multiplier, [s.value for s in slots]
                    )
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                    await self.message.edit(embed=embed)

                    if is_first:
                        await self.message.add_reaction("")
                        is_first = False
                    else:
                        await self.message.remove_reaction("", self.user)

                    if self.bet > self.coins:
                        has_busted = True
                    else:
                        await self.bot.wait_for(
                            "reaction_add", timeout=30, check=self.is_valid_reaction
                        )

            # They busted at this point
            amount = self.bet if self.bet > self.coins else self.initial_coins
            await self.bot.api.modify_gambling_profit(
                user_id=self.user.id, game="slots", amount=-1 * amount
            )
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            if self.initial_coins > self.coins:
                amount = -1 * (self.initial_coins - self.coins)
            else:
                amount = self.coins - self.initial_coins
            await self.bot.api.modify_gambling_profit(
                user_id=self.user.id, game="slots", amount=amount
            )
```

`commands.py`

```
    @commands.command(name="slots", aliases=["slot"])
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def slots_command(self, ctx: Context, bet: int) -> None:
        user_id = ctx.author.id
        if await self.currently_playing.get(f"gambling.{user_id}"):
            await ctx.send("❌ Already in another game.")
            return
        else:
            await self.currently_playing.set(f"gambling.{user_id}", 1)

        if not await self.is_valid_bet(bet):
            await ctx.send("❌ Bet must be a positive whole number.")
            return

        stats = await self.bot.api.get_economy_user(user_id=user_id)
        coins = stats["coins"]

        if await self.has_enough_coins(user_id, coins, bet):
            await SlotMachine(ctx, self.bot, ctx.author, coins, bet).game_loop()
        else:
            await ctx.send("❌ Not enough coins")

        await self.currently_playing.delete(f"gambling.{user_id}")
```

## Problem

When I was testing with 1 person, it works fantastic; however, when multiple people are running the same 'slots' command everyone receives a huge lag. It's almost as if one slot 'run' is waiting on the other.

## Questions

1. Does anyone see what is noticeably wrong with the code? Is there something that is blocking the main the thread? I suppose so?
2. What methods can I use to debug / investigate this issue? I'm currently running debug on asyncio, but it doesn't yield any warnings about the `slots` command?

At this point, I've become so frustrated that I'm about to switch over to a more 'async' friendly language such as `go` or `javascript`. That's a bit of an over-exaggerative / novice thought though ;)

Comment: I would recommend avoiding so intense (or any, unless you know what you're doing) use of `sync_to_async`. In your current code, it is completely unclear which function is truly async, which is sync but non-blocking, and which is sync-and-blocking. For example, methods like `has_row_of_two` definitely don't need the decorator, they can remain sync and you can just call them normally.